# scp not working but ssh works well

Tags: ssh, scp

I have just done a fresh install of Raspbian 64bits light.

When i do

```
ssh username@ipaddress scp
```

1. The ssh connection works well
2. the raspberry gives me the help toward scp

When i logout and then from the same terminal i write :

```
scp -v myfile username@ipaddress:/home/username/
```

I get :

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.164.1.42, user floupinette, command scp -v -t /home/floupinette/
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.164.1.42 [192.164.1.42] port 22.
```

Finally it give a time out error.

I want to precise that:

```
sftp username@ipaddress
```

is well working

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try extended verbosity when attempting your scp connection to show additional debug info so  use this cmd line `scp -vvv`.

This could be a scp issue rather then a Rasperrypi problem. Please see this thread for other solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/395356/why-doesn-t-scp-work-while-ssh-does